# Embed image not readable when sending a mail with symfony command

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have to send an email every day to notify administrators that there are user accounts to validate.
So I created a symfony command named 'app:notify-admin'.

The command retrieves all not validated accounts and then send an email like 'There are 8 users awaiting validation'.
I am using an email template which includes an image :

```
<div style="text-align: center; background-color: #EAECEF; padding: 8rem; color: #3E4147 !important;">
    <img style="max-width:100%; height:auto;" src="cid:logo" alt="Logo XX">

    <h1>
        {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    </h1>

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    <hr style="max-width: 50%">

    <p>
        Cordialement,
        <br>
        XXX
    </p>
</div>
```

The source of the image (cid:logo) is loaded on my mailer service with:

```
$this->email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->embedFromPath("images/logo.png", 'logo');
```

When i use this template to send emails in **a controller**, everything works fine.

***My problem*** is when i use this template to send emails in **a symfony command**, i got an error :

> In DataPart.php line 60:
> Path "images/logo.png" is not readable.

My file is here:
[image: Logo file]

I don't really know what can is wrong here... Can you help me?

Comment: check permission of file, maybe the user who run the symfony command can't execute/read the file

Comment: Does it need to specify the root with a slash in the beginning? like : `/images/logo.png` instead of `images/logo.png`

Comment: Have you tried using a twig path? https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/mailer/embedded-image#adding-a-twig-path-to-images

Comment: Adding a twig path resolved the problem, thanks !